# links not pointing to the right place

Tags: cakephp-2.0

So im trying to build a link using cakephp, here is the code im using:

echo $this->Html->link('FAQs',array('controller' => 'faqs','action' => 'index','full_base' => false));

and the link path im getting back is:

http://mysite.co.uk/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage25/ho/me/tr/mysite.co.uk/public_html/faqs

Im using a linux based hosting.

Has anyone experienced this before? or is able to offer some help.

thanks

Comment: Cool cool - you should really look at Ruby on Rails. what you've got there will be written like this: `<%= link_to "FAQ's", faq_index_path %>`

Comment: does anyone have any idea on this pls?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the problem isn't related to your use of full_base as it defaults to false anyway and should give you:

```
/faqs
```

The issue you seem to be having is that http://mysite.co.uk/ is not pointing to the root directory **public_html**. If you have acccess cPanel i.e. have login credentials for accessing your webhosting and root SSH access, have a look at this blog post and scroll down to **Changing Primary domains**:

http://blog.servint.net/2012/03/30/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/