# why my cakephp links not working correctly?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently using `cakephp` and  finding that if i construct links using:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('FAQs', array('controller'=>'faqs', 'action'=>'index')); ?>
```

I'm getting an absolute address returned which is not working.

Is anyone aware of how i can fix this?

On the faq's link if that helps.

Comment: Did you defined any route on Router.php?

Comment: do you mean routes.php? i have only changed the home page of cake php in here, other than that no.

Comment: okay just found router.php and havent been in here before. do i need to alter this file?

Comment: please verify whether mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: I have asked my provider if it has been and am awaiting  response, is there anyway i can check myself?

Comment: You [link](http://hometraderuk.co.uk/faqs) is clearly showing that you have not created `FaqsController` Are you sure you have created controller in App/Controller folder?
Also check if you mode_rewrite is enabled because our url is not constructed properly whereas dispatcher is working

Comment: apologies, had a typo, its working now, but im still getting an extremey long address in the url bar, is this due to the mod rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I placed an answer here [links not pointing to the right place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731678/links-not-pointing-to-the-right-place), to your Html->link issue, Are we still talking about the same issue?